# Remotely connect to USB scanner via LogMeIn or similar service

Tags: windows, macos, scanner, logmein

Is it possible to connect a USB scanner (Fujitsu ScanSnap) to a Windows machine and through LogMeIn or similar remote desktop apps/services be able to send the scanner connection to the remote machine? In my case, this would be a Mac running DEVONthink Pro Office.

That way I may be able to remotely update/work my DEVONthink database with the scanner connected elsewhere.

Comment: lets clarify... you are sitting at your mac and you want to use your fujitsu scanner remotely? This scanner is not physically near you?

Comment: Logman - I will to be able to work on a Windows machine, which will have the USB Scanner connected, and have the scanner feed be sent through the remote session to the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I will use dropbox and the OCR script from DEVONthink.

See: http://blog.devontechnologies.com/2010/08/tuesday-tip-automate-devonthink-using-hazel/